# Как отобразить информацию о связях таблиц БД ClickHouse в редакторе Tabix?

Tags: sql, база-данных, clickhouse

Всем привет

[image: Интерфейс Tabix]

Мне нужно увидеть информацию о связях между таблицами(foreign keys,primary keys)

В Postgresql например я мог получить эту информацию через ввод команды \d 'имя таблицы' в командной строке:

[image: Пример получения информации о сущности в Postgresql]

Подскажите пожалуйста как вы получаете данную информацию о ClickHouse БД.

Comment: а разве CH поддерживает foreign keys contraints? Само описание таблиц можно получить в табличном виде с помощью команды DESCRIBE

Comment: @Konst
Если в поле SQL запросов ввести "DESCRIBE", то появляется следующая ошибка:

Code: 62. DB::Exception: Syntax error: failed at position 86 (end of query) (line 10, col 9): . Expected one of: VIEW, SELECT subquery, compound identifier

Comment: https://clickhouse.com/docs/ru/sql-reference/statements/describe-table/